# how to replace special character in CDATA while parsing RSS Reader

Tags: android, rss

hii,

this is my data coming in xml format

description

![CDATA[JON CARDINELLI says that a question mark over Morne Steyn & #8217; s   goal-kicking means a question mark over his value at the 2011 World Cup.    After maintaining an unbeaten record at Loftus for two years, the Bulls are in a   position where they& #8217;ve suffered back-to-back defeats. While it is too early to write them off as play-off [...]]]

/description

now i want to replace & #8217;

plzz reply as early as possible, i want it urgent.

thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

CDATA is not parsed. You can replace it manually.

```
parsedString.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement);
```

In your case something like:

```
parsedString.replace("&#8217;", "’");
```

Comment: @Jazz You should use the exact sequence you want to replace. See if there are some whitespaces in &#8217; , because it will only replace a sequence if it is an exact match.

Comment: thank for your reply and u are right vendor. There is no whitespaces in between. and replace function is not working

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replace function use the following

parsedString.replaceAll("actualtext", "replacetext");

It is working for me